# featherlight loading msg before getting ajax data

Tags: featherlight.js

I have a typical link for which I would like to display the output in a popup window. To do that I'm using featherlight.
I would like to display some kind of a loading indicator until I get data from ajax call.
This is what I have tried:

```
    function wait() {
        document.querySelector('.featherlight-content').textContent='pls wait...';
    }

<a href='../servlet/NavWarn?action=send' data-featherlight="ajax" data-featherlight-before-content="wait();">
```

If I do that, it only prints "pls wait..." and the ajax data doesn't appear ever.
If I remove the "data-featherlight-before-content" from the A tag, ajax data appears correctly, but until it does I get an empty window (which is what I would like to avoid).

I've also tried doing it at featherlight's css (something like content:"pls wait...") without luck.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: replace `-content` by `-inner`.

*Details:*
The `featherlight-content` div contains the close box, any other static elements (like the navigation in case of the gallery), and the actual content called `featherlight-inner`. If you obliterate it, you destroy the `-inner` div and that's the one that displays your content!

I'll [improve the doc](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/issues/111) on this

Comment: Nice, but I think this functionality should be by default included in the library.

Comment: It's quite possible. There's already an [issue](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/issues/108) about that.

Comment: I also think it should come by default with the libary.